# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to print out the first trip recorded from each of 3 cities (the second line of each data file) for bike share system. However, it prints only one city and this error keeps showing:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'
```

I tried to search for the answer but I couldn't find any

Here is my code:

```
import csv 
from datetime import datetime 
from pprint import pprint 



def print_first_point(filename):
    """
    This function prints and returns the first data point (second row) from
    a csv file that includes a header row.
    """
    # print city name for reference
    city = filename.split('-')[0].split('/')[-1]
    print('\nCity: {}'.format(city))

    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        first_trip = csv.reader.fieldnames
        pprint(first_trip)
    # output city name and first trip for later testing
    return (city, first_trip)

# list of files for each city
data_files = ['./data/NYC-CitiBike-2016.csv',
              './data/Chicago-Divvy-2016.csv',
              './data/Washington-CapitalBikeshare-2016.csv',]

# print the first trip from each file, store in dictionary
example_trips = {}
for data_file in data_files:
    city, first_trip = print_first_point(data_file)
    example_trips[city] = first_trip
```

Comment: You forgot to call the function, `csv.reader().fieldnames`

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader is a function into which you must pass parameters, your current notation is looking for a variable "fieldnames" of csv.reader.

Ex: csv.reader(fieldnames);

Here's a link to an example. [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: it's not working, I think because I used DictReader object not a Reader object